# How to take last 3 months aws billing data using python flask

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need last 3 months AWS billing data in graph using python and python Flask.
i found some articles for this, i just created environment in my local machine. after i dont know how to take billing data using python & Python Flask script. Any one have idea please help me.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Boto](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to connect to AWS using Python.

In general you need to cover several items:

1. Authentication - You'll need to set up your credentials to be able to connect to AWS. Check the [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html)
2. Enable DBR or CUR reports in the billing console. This will export your monthly billing information to S3. Check the [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports-gettingstarted-turnonreports.html)
3. Once ready use Boto3 to download the reports and import them to DB, ES, whatever you're working with to process large excel files. Check the [Documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html)

Good luck!

**EDIT**:
For previous months you can just go to console -> bills and download the reports from the console directly, then process them in your application.